# Rewriting Outer apply to join for performance

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, outer-apply

Since I am not that familiar with Outer Apply, I am a bit lost with rewriting the one from my previous question to join. It worked well but not for large chunks of data. Any help with this appreciated.

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855014/t-sql-how-to-get-first-call-resolution-out-of-this)

Comment: Which version of sql server (please tag your questions appropriately)? Since v2012 [we have `LEAD()` and `LAG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: We are using 2008R2

Comment: The `APPLY` will compute data *row-wise* while a `JOIN` will try to connect two sets over a given criterion. In your case - as you want to get the *previous* entry the *row-wise* approach looks pretty much okay...

Comment: Yes it is funcional, but the query is taking far too long to execute, and I need to cut the execution time down as much as I can.

Comment: The approach of the previous question would need indexes on EntryTime and PhoneNumber. Do you have the needed indexes in your database? Are there other processes involved?

Answer (score 0):

You might use the following approach:

- Use a `CTE` to create a set and use `ROW_NUMBER` to number your calls.
- `ROW_NUMBER` allows to specify the `OVER()` clause with a `PARTITION BY` and an `ORDER BY` part

This will return a list of your phone calls, where each phone number as a consecutive index in the order of `EntryTime`.

You can then use a *self-join* to find the corresponding *previous* row.

```
declare @table table (
    PhoneNumber nvarchar(20),
    EntryTime datetime
)

insert into @table values ('(321) 546-7842', dateadd(hour,-30,getdate()));
insert into @table values ('(321) 546-7842', dateadd(hour,-3,getdate()));
insert into @table values ('(251) 546-9442', dateadd(hour,-2,getdate()));

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PhoneNumber ORDER BY EntryTime) AS CallIndex
          ,t.*
    FROM @table t 
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON t1.PhoneNumber=t2.PhoneNumber AND t1.CallIndex=t2.CallIndex-1
ORDER BY t1.PhoneNumber, t1.EntryTime;
```